# How to assign an action to the physical volume keys in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I would like my Codename One app to react to volume up / down keys (the physical keys that lay on the device side). Actually I already have a button that does the action but I would also like to offer the possibility to use the volume keys to launch the action.

I found the method `keyPressed()` which prototype reads

```
public void keyPressed(int keyCode)
```

but I was not able to actually find the keyCode constant for volume up / down.

How can I assign the volume up / down keys to an action with Codename One ?

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key pressed/released won't be invoked for volume since that is way too deep in the native call chain and very device dependent. Volume keys are always treated as a special case so we make them do "what's expected" and provide some tailored callbacks but we don't support the use case of "re-purposing" volume keys.

It might be possible by changing the `AndroidImplementation` class to include a special case (possibly triggered via a display property) and submitting a pull request for that.

Comment: Thanks @Shai, so is keyPressed() method only there for devices with a physical keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

hope it's OK to jump on this thread: @Shai, you mention that CN1 "provides some tailored callbacks" for the volume buttons. I tried finding this in the documentation and the code (searching on "volume") but didn't succeed - can you give a hint on how to get such callbacks? My use case is to check if a volume button is pushed when starting up the app and take some special actions.

Comment: Any hints on this question?