# How to tailor callbacks" for the volume buttons?

Tags: codenameone

In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976239/how-to-assign-an-action-to-the-physical-volume-keys-in-codename-one/60389256#60389256) on SO, it is mentioned that CN1 "provides some tailored callbacks" for the volume buttons. I tried finding this in the documentation and the code (searching on "volume") but didn't succeed - can you give a hint on how to get such callbacks? My use case is to check if a volume button is pushed when starting up the app and take some special actions.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking about the `android.headphoneCallback` build hint mentioned [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

Dealing with volume buttons is very platform specific. It's even tricky within the boundaries of a specific OS. So we don't expose an API to directly handle volume buttons.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I was just referring to what you wrote in the other thread: “Volume keys are always treated as a special case so we make them do “what’s expected” and provide some *tailored callbacks*.” I understood that as callbacks for the volume buttons, but I can see that was a misunderstanding. Too bad, these days, with the few keys left on a phone, you could really use ways exploit them ;-)

Comment: Some devices do send volume keys as regular key events but this isn't universal and we don't expose that to avoid inconsistency.